# How to read and write JSON data from a file

Tags: c, json, linux, file, json-c

I'm using a json-c library in Linux.

I have a JSON object :

```
jobj = {
    "person1": {
        "Id": 12354,
        "age": 12,
        "place": "someplace"
    },
    "person2": {
        "Id": 123,
        "age": 122,
        "place": "someplace"
    }
}
```

I want to store this data to a file and later I want to read json data from the same.

Please give some idea how to do it.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Do you mean _a_ json-c library or do you mean _the_ [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki) library?

Comment: json re-validated @BLUEPIXY

Comment: yup json-c library for C language@Gerhardh

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question:

- you are using a json-c library for linux. There are quite a few available, notably `libjson`, `json-c`, `jansson`...
- read the documentation for the one you selected
- find an online tutorial
- read sample code...

We cannot provide a precise answer for a completely open question.